# How can I search for a specific word inside all my blade views in Laravel 5.5 or else

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I want to know how can I show pages that contain a specific word written by random user in input text, because some contents are static.

P.S : If what I'm talking about is deprecated, can you propose to me a best solution for doing such functionality?

Comment: Are you looking for static text, or something from the database? Are you looking for yourself to find where it's located, or are is it going to be an end-user looking?

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I'm looking to return all views that contain a word written by a user in the input field, but because some elements, I can't use query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to keep your data in database. It will allow you to search and display content dynamically. Also in case you have some static pages, you can put them in database just for searching purposes if it's solution in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir ! So, If I understand clearly, I should store all my blade body contents into database? For exemple, when an administrator create a new article ( because I'm creating a blog website ), what are elements that will allow me to return links that redirect to blades that contain the writen word by users ? Thank you sir!

Comment: You need to find valid article in database in controller and pass this into view (Blade) and display what you want in view